# How to read file into matrix character by character in python?

Tags: python, matrix, character

In Python, I have a file like this:

```
foo
fo
f
foo
foooo
```

And I want to read it into a matrix like:

```
[['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', ' '],
 ['f', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['f', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', ' '],
 ['f', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']]
```

So that each individual list is the same length, and that length is the length of the longest list, filling with spaces to get to that length.

Here's my code so far:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

for c in data:
    ????
```

Comment: What's your code? :)

Comment: I haven't tried writing code to do this yet; I can't figure out where to start.

Comment: Here is a hint: you need to know the length of the longest string (from your file).

Comment: I figure that much out, and I have the string made out of the file, but it's mainly the filling with spaces and creating the sub-arrays that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Another hint, the `numpy` library is great for this. :) Consider using it, if you can use an external lib

Comment: Ok so you DO have code, mind showing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build like this,

```
text = open(file_name).read()
lst = text.split('\n')
print [list(i+' '*(len(max(lst))-len(i))) for i in lst]
```

Get the maimum lenth vale in the `lst` and get the substarcted value with the current vale, And get addup `' '` fields,

**Result**

```
[['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', ' '],
 ['f', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['f', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', ' '],
 ['f', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the first step is to find the maximum length string:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    max_len = max(map(len,lines))
```

Once you have this, you can build your array by padding the strings with the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), so for each particular line, that might look like

```
modified_line = "{:{max_len}}".format(original_line, max_len)
```

This will pad `original_line` within a string which is `max_len` long (left aligned).  The syntax of the `format` function can be a little tricky, so I gave you a head start on that, but the rest is simple and I will leave up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using [**max**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max) and [**str.ljust**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=ljust#str.ljust) functions:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    max_len = len(max(lines, key=len))
    result = [list(l.ljust(max_len, ' ')) for l in lines]

print(result)
```